# Updating global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to update my global variable on click. Basically, all my links have IDs which I want to change my global variable to once clicked. Please see my code below:

```js
var selectedBrand = "";

$(document).on("click", ".style-block a", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var styleID = $(this).attr("id").replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
  var selectedBrand = styleID;
  $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'))
  $(this).reload();
});

$('#brand-list').html(selectedBrand);
```

So as a result I want to show selected ID within div id="brand-list" (as per my code).

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `var` in the child function you are creating a local variable, for the inner function. That is why the global variable was not being updated. `selectedBrand = styleID;` is enough inside the inner function.

```
var selectedBrand = "";

$(document).on("click", ".style-block a", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    var styleID = $(this).attr("id").replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
    selectedBrand = styleID;
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'))
    $(this).reload();   
});

$('#brand-list').html(selectedBrand);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `var` from the `selectedBrand` inside the event handler. By removing `var`, the variable `selectedBrand` is searched in the scope-chain until it is finally found on the Global object.

When you add `var` to a variable inside function the variable is function scoped i.e. cannot be accessed from outside of that function.

```js
var selectedBrand = "";

$(document).on("click", ".style-block a", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var styleID = $(this).attr("id").replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');

  selectedBrand = styleID; // Remove var from here

  $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'))
  $(this).reload();
});

$('#brand-list').html(selectedBrand);
```

Or, you can also use

```
window.selectedBrand = styleID;
```

to update the value of global variable explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use var again inside child function. replace this `var selectedBrand = styleID;` to just this `selectedBrand = styleID;`. Your using var selectedBrand inside on change creates local variable which is local, NOT Global

It should be like this

```
 var selectedBrand = "";

 $(doem cument).on("click", ".style-block a", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var styleID = $(this).attr("id").replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
 selectedBrand = styleID;
 $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'))
 $(this).reload();
 });

 $('#brand-list').html(selectedBrand);
```